# bcp connection error 80070002 in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, bcp

I have a standard bcp command like:

```
bcp "MyTable" out "c:\temp\test_file.txt" -c -S"MyMachine\Sqlinstance" -U"MyID" -P"MyPW"
```

which works perfect if I use it from cmd prompt manually.

When using it from the *browser* it returns user error message:

> error '80070002'
>   ?, line 0

This is what I have in the VBScript:

```
option explicit
dim cmdLine, oshell
cmdLine = "bcp ""MyTable"" out ""c:\temp\test_file.txt"" -c -S""MyMachine\Sqlinstance"" -U""MyID""
-P""MyPW"""

Set oshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell") 
oshell.run (cmdLine)
set oshell = nothing
```

- Under the SQL Security (Server Roles) I have user "MyID" as member of public and bulkadmin.
- Under the Database / Security / Users, I have user "MyID" as dbo. Owned Schemas are all unchecked.

What is missing?

Comment: Try running the command in CMD rather than directly: `oshell.run "%COMSPEC% /c " & cmdline`. Or like this: `oshell.run "%COMSPEC% /k " & cmdline, 1, True`, so that you can see the output the command produces.

Comment: oshell.run "%COMSPEC% /c " & cmdline -- returns no error message and it does not do anything, it is as if the command is totally ignored. The /k switch is the same but keeps the browser on, spinning.